# Deploying a webpart to multiple site collections?

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

Is it possible to Deploy a Webpart to multiple Site Collections, and not only to one?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SP2010 then there can be two type of deployments, Sand´box or Farm solution.

If you have built a farm solution, then you can go the Feature folder in 14 hive and look for your feature name. Once you get your feature name you would see your `Feature.xml` lying there.

In `Feature.xml` there would be a scope; if it is web then scope is site, if it is site then scope in Site collection and it is farm then scope is farm.

If you have deployed the feature where scope is site then you can activate at each site collection level and if it is  web then you need to activate for each site you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Site scoped feature for your web parts, you can use the Enable-SPFeature cmdlet in PowerShell to enable the feature on all the site collections you want to: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607803(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: how do i se if i have a site scoped solution?

Comment: Where do you activate it ("Site Features", "Site Collection Features", etc.)?  If it is a custom solution, you can see that when editing the feature in Visual Studio.

Comment: Scope:Site and the items are in the Feature

Comment: I have never heard about site scoped solution, what is it? oO

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is scoped at the site or site collection. Either way you can activate it with enable-spfeature.

Comment: @TomResing, the solution could not be site or site collection scoped, feature can. There are only farm and sandbox solution. If solution is a sandbox it can be applied for only one site collection, in other way it applies for all site collection through web application. The solution that can be applied for one web does not exist.

Comment: I agree with @Alexander. The wording in this answer is confusing. Solutions are not scoped. Features are.

Comment: Nice catch ;-), edited.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. 
If you have a web part available in one site collections, the feature is activated at the site or site collection level, but the solution is installed to the farm and deployed per web application.

To add the web part to other site collections, you can either activate it through site settings or automate it with PowerShell.

To activate it through PowerShell see Enable-SPFeature: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607803.aspx

Comment: not a farm, solution is deployed to the web application :)

Comment: good point. I've clarified the wording.